# Find if value is equal to or between values in 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, csv, multidimensional-array

I have a python script which captures log data and turns it into a 2D array.

The next portion of the script is aiming to loop through a .csv file and evaluate the first column of every row and determine if that value is equal to or between the values in the 2D array. If it is, then mark the last column as TRUE. If not, mark it as FALSE.

For example, if my 2d Array looks like this:

```
[[1542053213, 1542053300], [1542055000, 1542060105]]
```

And my csv file looked like the following:

```
1542053220, Foo, Foo, Foo
1542060110, Foo, Foo, Foo
```

The last column for the first row should read TRUE (or 1) while the last column for the second fow should read FALSE (or 0).

My current code looks like below:

```
from os.path import expanduser
import re
import csv
import codecs

#Setting variables
#Specifically, set the file path to the reveal log
filepath = expanduser('~/LogAutomation/programlog.txt')
csv_filepath = expanduser('~/LogAutomation/values.csv')
tempStart = ''
tempEnd = ''

print("Starting Script")

#open the log
with open(filepath) as myFile:
    #read the log
    all_logs = myFile.read()
myFile.close()

#Create regular expressions
starting_regex = re.compile(r'\[(\d+)\s+s\]\s+Starting\s+Program')
ending_regex = re.compile(r'\[(\d+)\s+s\]\s+Ending\s+Program\.\s+Stopping')

#Create arrays of start and end times
start_times = list(map(int, starting_regex.findall(all_logs)))
end_times = list(map(int, ending_regex.findall(all_logs)))

#Create 2d Array
timeArray = list(map(list, zip(start_times, end_times)))

#Print 2d Array
print(timeArray)

print("Completed timeArray construction")

#prints the csv file
with open(csv_filepath, 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(codecs.iterdecode(csvfile, 'utf-8'))

    for row in reader:
        currVal = row[0]
            #if currVal is equal to or in one of the units in timeArray, mark last column as true
            #else, mark last column as false

csvfile.close()

print("Script completed")
```

I have successfully been able to iterate through my .csv and grab the first column's value for every row, but I do not know how to do the comparison. I am unfamiliar with the 2D array data structure unfortunately in regards to checking in between values. Additionally, the number of columns in my .csv file can fluctuate, thus is anyone aware of a non-static way to determine the "last column" to be able to write to the column after that in the file?

Would someone be able to offer me some assistance?

Comment: I dont understand the expected output. You want to put the TRUE/FALSE as last element of the row from 2D array? add TRUE/FALSE to the row in 2D array? or to add to the csv row? in that case where do you save the result? same file?

Comment: Sorry you don't understand. The goal, as written, is to write to the last column of the .csv file (in the example code, values.csv) with TRUE if the first column's value is equal to or between the values in the 2D array. If it is not, then write FALSE in the last column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to iterate over the list of lists and check if the value is in any of the intervals. Here's a simple way to do it:

```
with open(csv_filepath, 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(codecs.iterdecode(csvfile, 'utf-8'))
    input_rows = [row for row in reader]

with open(csv_filepath, 'w') as outputfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outputfile)

    for row in input_rows:
        currVal = int(row[0])
        ok = 'FALSE'

        for interval in timeArray:
            if interval[0] <= curVal <= interval[1]:
                ok = 'TRUE'
                break

        writer.writerow(row + [ok])
```

The above code will write the result in the same file, so be careful. I also removed `csvfile.close()` because if you use the `with` statement the file will get closed for you automatically.

Comment: Hi @Marco Bonelli, thanks a lot for your response. Please give me a moment (maybe 30 mins) to integrate and test with my code, and I will get right back to you. Can you explain the `interval in TimeArray` line?

Comment: @JerryM. sure: just like you did `for row in reader` you can use the `for ... in ...` syntax to iterate over any list (or iterable object in general). Your `timeArray` is a list of lists, so you can iterate over it with `for interval in timeArray`. Once inside the `for`, the `interval` variable will hold the value of the current element being processed, so in your case it will first be `[1542053213, 1542053300]`, and then `[1542055000, 1542060105]`.

Comment: Hi Marco. Running this code ends up deleting the values in my .csv file. I need to write to the same csv file I am opening. Hopefully this helps. I appreciate your response so far.

Comment: @JerryM. I was assuming you wanted the result in another file. I changed the code, now the changes are made directly on the same file. See if that works for you. Also by "marking the last column as TRUE or FALSE" do you mean that you want to replace the value in the last column or that you want to *add* a new column after the last one?

Comment: I would like to add a column, I apologize for not being clear.

Comment: @JerryM. ok, fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

I will go for something more pythonic.

```
compare = lambda x, y, t: (x <= int(t) <= y)
with open('output.csv', 'w') as outputfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outputfile)
    with open(csv_filepath, 'rb') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(codecs.iterdecode(csvfile, 'utf-8'))

    for row in reader:
        currVal = row[0]
        #if currVal is equal to or in one of the units in timeArray, mark last column as true
        #else, mark last column as false
        match = any(compare(x, y, currVal) for x, y in timeArray)
        write.writerow(row + ['TRUE' if match else 'FALSE'])

    csvfile.close()
outputfile.close()
```

Comment: After fixing some indents with your solution, I am now receiving `SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing` on `line 79`

Comment: missing )m sorry hard to copy with indents on python

Comment: No problem @Tzomas, I know it is weird. I have a question. Is it possible to both open, read, and edit the same file? Ideally, I don't want to create a separate output file. I think I edited your code incorrectly. Would you be willing to chat?

Comment: `    for row in reader:
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/codecs.py", line 1034, in iterdecode
    for input in iterator:
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.`

Was the error.

Comment: I never use codecs have to say, i think you can read the file as regular. You can't write on a opened file. Just modify the code to read first (if the file is not so so big, you shouldn't have problems) and then close the file,  once it's close, open it again but this time to write on it, you will overwrite the content so care. test with a copy first

Comment: I will try this method, and comment back.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183737/discussion-between-jerry-m-and-tzomas).